NextJS 14 AuthJS Social Provider Middleware - Add new user to MongoDB after JWT sign-in
I have a NextJS 14 app and have added AuthJS to allow users to login with social provider credentials only at this point via a custom signin page. I am using the JWT strategy in AuthJS to athenticate as, from my understanding, the AuthJS MongoDB adapter doesn't work with NextJS middleware due to edge compatibility.
What I am trying to achieve is when the user authenticates from the custom signin page, check if the user's email address exists in MongoDB. If yes, continue to the app; if no, create the user and then continue to the app. I am able to achieve this in the middleware and on each individual page but it seems inefficient to me to check if the user exists on each page/middleware call.
What I would prefer is this check to happen in the finally block in my custom signin page server action as follows:
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { signIn, auth, providerMap } from "@/auth";
import { AuthError } from "next-auth";
import Image from "next/image";
import Logo from "../../../public/images/Sign-In-Large---Default.png";
import { Syncopate } from "next/font/google";
import dbConnect from "@/lib/dbConnect";
import User from "@/models/User";

const synco = Syncopate({ subsets: ["latin"], weight: ["400", "700"] });

export default function SignInPage() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen pb-[8rem] bg-gray-50">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center gap-8 bg-white border border-gray-100 shadow-md rounded-[1rem] m-6 p-8 justify-items-center">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center rounded-[0.5rem]">
          <p
            className={`${synco.className} text-[#0077B5] text-6xl text-center`}
          >
            App
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="my-8 text-center w-[75%]">
          <p className="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Welcome to App!</p>
        </div>
        <div className="h-[1px] w-full bg-gray-200"></div>
        <div className="w-[90%] flex justify-center">
          {Object.values(providerMap).map((provider, index) => (
            <form
              key={index}
              action={async () => {
                "use server";
                try {
                  const res = await signIn(provider.id, {
                    redirect: true,
                    redirectTo: "/",
                  });
                } catch (error) {
                  if (error instanceof AuthError) {
                    return redirect(`${SIGNIN_ERROR_URL}?error=${error.type}`);
                  }
                  throw error;
                } finally {
                  const session = await auth();
                  const user = session.user;
                  const userEmail = session.user.email;
                  let dbUser;
                  await dbConnect();
                  try {
                    dbUser = await User.findOne({ email: userEmail });
                    if (!dbUser) {
                      await User.create({
                        email: userEmail,
                        videos: ["Video 1", "Video 2", "Video 3"],
                      });
                    }
                  } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  }
                }
              }}
            >
              <button type="submit">
                <Image src={Logo} alt="logo" width={300} height={300} />
              </button>
            </form>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

However, when I signin, the const user = session.user; line returns null even though the user has authenticated in the try block. How do I get access to the user in auth().session in the finally block once the authentication in the try block has completed?
TIA

I have come up with a workaround which doesn't look very elegant but seems to work:
I moved the finally block function into a separate API route and changed the redirectTo to the new API route. In the API route, I processed the user then redirected back to the original redirectTo path:
app/signin/page.js
//...start of signin page
try {
  console.log("Here");
  const res = await signIn(provider.id, {
    redirect: true,
    // Changed the redirect URL to the API route
    redirectTo: "/api/db",
  });
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof AuthError) {
    return redirect(`${SIGNIN_ERROR_URL}?error=${error.type}`);
  }
  throw error;
}
// finally block removed
//... rest of signin page

app/api/db/route.js
import dbConnect from "@/lib/dbConnect";
import User from "@/models/User";
import { auth } from "@/auth";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
  const session = await auth();
  const userEmail = session.user.email;
  await dbConnect();
  try {
    const dbUser = await User.findOne({ email: userEmail });
    if (!dbUser) {
      await User.create({
        email: userEmail,
        videos: ["Video 1", "Video 2", "Video 3"],
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ msg: error });
  } finally {
    redirect("/");
  }
}

One point to note in the API route: It turns out redirect can only be used in the finally block in API routes, not in the try or catch blocks.
